# Trying to run executable (application/x-executable) but to no avail

Tags: 13.04

I am trying to run a executable (application/x-executable) file I have tried everything it 
I am trying to install a software which is part of a Behringer X32... please guys help please please please.What is the correct way or line to run via the terminal.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How are you trying to execute it? What errors you get? Have you checked it has execution permission?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem.  I'm new to Ubuntu and Linux, but I found that when I right clicked and selected the properties for the file, and clicked on the "Permissions" tab, the "execute" option at the bottom was NOT selected for me.  Checking this box resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

This is too little info to give a good answer.
On the basic side if you want to execute a command on the terminal and that executable is in the same folder:
`./nameoffile` 
(Note the `./` in front.)
However if you have no execute rights set for the script they can easily be set with:
`chmod u+x nameoffile` (adds execute rights to the file) 
Though this also demands a drive with execute privileges. Usually things like USB keys/drives do not allow execution of code on linux.

These are the most basic basics, since you say install, is your file really an executable or a .deb or such? In that case right click it and chose "Open in software center" to start the install.

Try to be more specific in the future, exactly what file, where did you get it etc. 
If you do people can help with your specific problem.